# What is CLK_PER_SEC?

Tags: c

While reading some pages in The C Programming Language 2e, I found this.

> `clock_t clock(void)` : `clock` returns the processor time used by the
>   program since the beginning of execution, or -1 if unavailable.
>   `clock()/CLK_PER_SEC` is a time in seconds.

What is `CLK_PER_SEC`? It doesn't look like a typo.

Comment: Why not try it? It's definitely not a typo, it is short for possibly: Clocks per second.

Comment: is it `time.h`? weird http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#index-CLOCKS_005fPER_005fSEC

Answer (score 3):

The manpage for `clock(3)` seems to mention `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. glibc follows the same convention. It seems that the text you quoted is from K&R 2nd edition, which is quite dated now. It is possible that the standard library used `CLK_PER_SEC` back then, but it is certainly not the case right now.

Comment: There is no such thing in glibc for example, there is only CLOCKS_PER_SEC

Comment: @Andrey Yeah I had that feeling too, and just confirmed it. Thanks for noting. I am updating my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This was likely a mistake in the K&R 2nd book. The most recent reprints have `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`, that is defined in ANSI/ISO C standard (C89/C99/C11).

From the [errata](http://www.lysator.liu.se/%28nobg%29/c/c-errata.html):

> Appendix B changes:
>
> - p 255: Change `CLK_TCK` to `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

Don't ask me what `CLK_TCK` is.

Comment: Hum, `CLK_TCK` is an obsolete name for `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. I don't see where they used `CLK_TCK` though. Maybe this errata entry is wrong? It should be *Change CLK_PER_SEC to CLOCKS_PER_SEC*.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: You may be right, I thought of the same explanation, but I am not so sure to say it definitely.

Comment: Yeah, either way I think this is the true correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The standard macro for clock ticks per second is `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/.

Some platforms define `CLK_PER_SEC` as an alias to `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

Comment: @Andrey, Searching for `CLK_PER_SEC` in google shows a lot of files.

Answer (score 0):

It.s  clock ticks per second. U can find more information here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/CPU-Time.html

Comment: Except that there is no such constant with this name

Comment: Are u including the time.h library?